# Deleted directory after git reset --hard @{u}

Tags: git

I cloned an empty repo from github (let's named it repoA) and added a directory (named results) in it locally (so repoA/results)

Then I did a `git add results` to add the results directory to the repo.
Then `git commit -m "add results directory"`. Finally `git push`

During the push I had an error because of a too big file I forgot to remove :

```
Total 5660 (delta 2779), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2779/2779), done.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 7b1b7d4f8a8e398ef7184a6410f06c66
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File results/quality/R1.linker.fastq is 360.01 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/XXX/repoA.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: impossible de pousser des références vers 'https://github.com/XXX/repoA.git'
```

So I deleted in local the big file. and then `git commit -m "delete big file"`
I tried `git push` again but I had the same error.

I tried `git reset`  and `git checkout` with no impact.

Then I did  `git reset --hard @{u}`

```
HEAD is now at 78022b7 Initial commit
```

But now the /results directory disappeared from my computer and is not pushed on github ... Is there anything to do to repair my (stupid) error. These results were quiet valuable for me ..

Thanks a lot

> Edit

As suggested I did I did `git reset 2f6116c` :

```
Modifications non indexées après reset :
D   results/benchmarkBlast/benchmarkBlast.R
D   results/benchmarkBlast/benchmark_blast_bowtie_01092017.jpg
D   results/benchmarkBlast/benchmark_blast_bowtie_01092017.pdf
D   results/benchmarkBlast/bowtie2_10000000_1_LTR.txt
D   results/benchmarkBlast/results/BLV/blast_1000000_10_10_BLV.txt
D   results/benchmarkBlast/results/BLV/blast_1000000_10_1_BLV.txt
D   results/benchmarkBlast/results/BLV/blast_1000000_10_2_BLV.txt
etc..
```

and still nothing in my directory ?
D   figures/benchmarkBlast/results/BLV/blast_1000000_10_3_BLV.txt

> Edit

I solved by doing :

```
git reset -- results
git checkout -- results
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR: make a new branch name to recover your existing commit(s)

You can do this with `git branch`.

#### Long explanation

1. "don't panic" :-)
2. Realize that what a commit *is*, in Git, is a permanent, unchangeable snapshot of whatever you had in what Git calls your *index* or *staging area* or *cache* (three words for the same thing).

Each commit remembers its previous (or *parent*) commit.  You made two commits (probably one via GitHub during creating the repository, but the effect is the same).  The first one has *no* parent, because it can't: it was the first commit.  (We call this commit a *root* commit.)

Then you made a second commit, but since this commit had a previous commit, Git made the second commit use the first commit as its parent.  If we call the first commit `A`—rather than its actual name, some incomprehensible hash ID like `78022b7...`—and call the second commit `B` (instead of `2f6116c...`), we can draw the situation like this:

```
A <-B
```

Commit `B` (`2f6116c...`) lets Git find commit `A` (`78...`) because `B` store's `A`'s ID.  But Git needs some way to find `B` first, because their hash IDs have no relationship to the order you made the commits.  This is where branch names like `master` come in:

```
A <-B   <-- master
```

We say that the name `master` *points to* commit `B`, because it locates commit `B` for us.

#### What `git reset` does is complicated but it starts with moving branch names

Initially, you have these two commits in your repository, with `master` pointing to `B`, and you try to `git push` and that fails.

You then ran `git reset --hard @{u}`.  This does *three* things, but let's worry about the first thing first: it moves the *branch name*.

Commits are permanent and unchangeable.  `git reset` does not affect the commits, because it *can't*.  But it does affect the name—in this case `master`—because names *aren't* permanent, and *are* changeable.

The commit sequence `A<-B` remains in your repository, but let's draw it a bit differently so that we can point `master` to `A`:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B   [abandoned]
```

Now if we're Git and we start by looking at `master`, we find commit `A` and show it, and then commit `A` is the root commit (has no parent) so we stop.

Commit `B` is still in there, with no name.  Fortunately the *reflog* (which you've already seen now) saves its hash ID, which saves it, for as long as the reflog entry stays around (at least 30 days by default).

#### Reset does one, two, or three things

Remember above that I said `git reset --hard @{u}` did three things.  Moving the branch name was only one of the three.

The other two things `git reset` can, and with `--hard` does, do are:

- Re-set the index.

  The index (which again is also called the staging area or the cache) is perhaps best described as "what will go into the *next* commit that you make".
- Re-set the *work-tree*.

  The work-tree is actually the only obvious one of these things: it's where you do your work.  In the work-tree, your files have their usual form, and are all available to all the normal computer programs.  Things in the index and inside commits are in a special Git-only form.

You can have Git stop after doing just one thing: `git reset --soft`.  This moves a branch name, and does not touch the index and work-tree.

You can have Git stop after doing two things: `git reset --mixed`.  This moves a branch name, and re-sets the index.

Or, you can have Git do all three things: `git reset --hard`.  This moves a branch name, re-sets the index, and re-sets the work-tree.

What you might like to have is something like this:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B   <-- recovery
```

This will give you two branch names for the two existing commits.

If you currently have the name `master` pointing to commit `A`, you can just add a new branch name, `recovery`, pointing to commit `B`:

```
git branch recovery 2f6116c
```

will do that.

If the name `master` currently points to commit `B`, you can do another `git reset` to make it point to commit `A` again.  You can create the name `recovery` *first* and don't have to spell out `B`'s hash ID:

```
git branch recovery
git reset 78022b7
```

Each time you run `git reset` like this, you move the *current* branch name—the branch that `git status` says that you're on—to the given commit.  If you use `--mixed` (the default), you also reset the index.  If you use `--hard`, you also reset the work-tree.  But whatever commit hash you give, you move the current *branch name* to point to that commit.

The commits themselves stay where they are, permanent and unchanging.  What changes are:

- your branch names;
- your index/staging-area; and
- your work-tree.

Anything you have saved away with `git commit` is stored permanently, unchangingly, for as long as there is a branch name by which you can find the commit *or* a reflog entry keeping an otherwise-abandoned commit alive.  Only after about a month when the reflog entries start expiring will abandoned commits really go away.

#### Reset actually can do even more things

It took me long enough to answer this that you came up with `git reset -- results`.  This is yet another thing `git reset` can do: it "moves" the current branch name to where it is now, which has no effect, and then it re-sets some *specific* index entry or entries to whatever is in the new current commit.  This lets you then run `git checkout` to extract the index entry into the work-tree.

(You can also extract directly from a commit, which copies first into the index and then into the work-tree.  It's a good idea to keep in mind that, at all times, Git is working with *three* copies of every file: one in the `HEAD` commit, one in the index, and a third one in the work-tree!)

Answer (score 0):

- `git reflog` will give you the operations done
- From there find the operation hash done **before** hard reset
- `git reset <commithash>`
- If `reset` will bring you back when files were deleted (as it seem in your case) because you did not point to right operation hash, you might need to perform a `git checkout -- .` in order to restore them.

Comment: I've 3 results :
1: `78022b7 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to @{u}`
#
2: `2f6116c HEAD@{1}: commit: put results`
#
3: `78022b7 HEAD@{2}: clone: from https://github.com/XXX/repoA.git`

Comment: @NicolasRosewick I suppose `2f6116c` is the hash you are searching for

Comment: I did git reset 2f6116c (not reflog) but no directory there... I edited my question

Comment: `git reflog` just gives you operations you did

Comment: @NicolasRosewick what `git status says`? I can see that you have correct result with a big `D` (stands for *DELETE*) near your files. You should perform again a `git add *` I suppose

Comment: All my files are reported as deleted [supprimé in french]
supprimé :        results/benchmarkBlast/benchmarkBlast.R

Comment: @NicolasRosewick perform a `git add *` as suggested

Comment: I did git add * but no impact. I still do not see the results directory. Doing ls shows only README.md and the .git directory

Comment: @NicolasRosewick what `git status` says?

Comment: same as before git add * . So supprimé : results/benchmarkBlast/benchmarkBlast.R. And the last line : aucune modification n'a été ajoutée à la validation (utilisez "git add" ou "git commit -a"). So in english "no modification has nee, added to validation (use git add or git commit -a) "

Comment: ok I solved it myself by doing git reset -- results and git checkout -- results . ouf !!!! Thanks again DonCallisto